# Fortran beginner - output file shows NaN

Tags: fortran

I wrote a simple Fortran program for the three body problem using Euler-Richardson algorithm. For some reason the output files give nothing but NaN. Would the issue be solved by using subroutines or functions?

```
PROGRAM Threebody
IMPLICIT none



!************** Variable declarations ***************

!real(8), parameter :: G = 6.6738D-11

INTEGER :: IOSTAT, dt, t_step, io_error, i
DOUBLE PRECISION:: st, g, m0, m1, m2, force0x, force0y, force1x, force1y, force2x, force2y, n0, n1, n2, x0,v0,x1,v1,x2,v2,y0,w0,y1
DOUBLE PRECISION:: w1,y2,w2

m0 = 1.d0                               ! the masses of the three bodies
m1 = 1.d0
m2 = 1.d0

g = 9.80d0                              ! m/s^2 s due to gravity

t_step = 1

y0 = 0.d0                           
x0 = 0.d0
v0 = 0.d0                               
w0 = 0.d0

y1 = 0.d0                           
x1 = 1.d0
v1 = 2.d0                               
w1 = 1.118d0

y2 = 0.d0                           
x2 = -1.d0
v2 = -1.118d0                               
w2 = 0.d0


dt = 1  ! time step

OPEN(unit=5, file='out.txt', status='replace',action='write', IOSTAT=io_error)
OPEN(unit=6, file='out1.txt', status='replace',action='write', IOSTAT=io_error)
OPEN(unit=7, file='out2.txt', status='replace',action='write', IOSTAT=io_error)





! particle no.1
DO i=0,1000,t_step                          ! 1000 is the total time

st=i!/10.d0

n0 = sqrt(((x2 - x1)**2 + (y2 - y1)**2)**3)

force0x  = (- m1*(( x0 - x1 ) / n2)) - (m2*(( x0 - x2 ) / n1))

x0 = x0 + (w0 + 0.5*force0x*st)*st
w0 = w0 + force0x*st

force0y  = (- m1 * (( y0 - y1 ) / n2)) - (m2 * (( y0 - y2 ) / n1))

y0 = y0 + (v0 + 0.5*force0y*st)*st
v0 = v0 + force0y*st


WRITE(5,*) i*t_step, x0, y0, n0

END DO




! particle no.2
DO i=0,1000,dt              

st=i

n1 = sqrt(((x0 - x2 )**2 + (y0 - y2)**2)**3) 

force1x  = (- m2 * (( x1 - x0 ) / (n0))) - m0 * (( x1 - x2 ) / n2)

x1 = x1 + (w1 + 0.5*force1x*st)*st
w1 = w1 + force1x*st

force1y  = (- m2 * ( y1 - y0 ) / n0) - (m0 * (( y1 - y2 ) / n2))

y1 = y1 + (v1 + 0.5*force1y*st)*st
v1 = v1 + force1y*st


WRITE(6,*) i*t_step, x1, y1
END DO




! particle no.3
DO i=0,1000,dt  

st=i            

n2 = sqrt ( ( ( x1 - x0 )**2 + ( y1 - y0 )**2 )**3 )

force2x = (- m0 * (( x2 - x0 ) / n1)) - (m1 * (( x2 - x1 ) / n0))

x2 = x2 + (w2 + 0.5*force2x*st)*st
w2 = w2 + force2x*st

force2y = (- m0 * (( y2 - y0 ) / n1)) - (m1 * (( y2 - y1 ) / n0))

y2 = y2 + (v2 + 0.5*force2y*st)*st
v2 = v2 + force2y*st


WRITE(7,*) i*t_step, x2, y2, n2
END DO


CLOSE(unit=5)
CLOSE(unit=6)
CLOSE(unit=7)

END PROGRAM Threebody
```

Answer (score 3):

Compiling with -Wall in gfortran gives you a hint:

```
f.f90:56:0: warning: ‘n1’ may be used uninitialized in this function [-Wmaybe-uninitialized]
      force0x  = (- m1*(( x0 - x1 ) / n2)) - (m2*(( x0 - x2 ) / n1))
```

n1 and n2 are not initialized so they may contain anything. In my case, 6.95e-310, causing force0x to give NaN.

To debug this, you can print the variables on screen to check when they are becoming NaN. For that, please don't use units below 10, because they may be reserved. I think that Unit 5 is standard output so by reusing it you cannot print anything on screen.

Comment: Appart from the bug, if I'm not wrong, you should have only one loop and compute the new positions for the three particles one after another, not 1000 times the loop for the first particle, then the second, etc.